# Accessing phpMyAdmin remotely

Tags: lamp, remote-access, phpmyadmin, redirect

I've installed and got everything working and set up fine and I can install phpMyAdmin fine as well, but I am unable to access it remotely.

I've tried adding the following into /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf with no luck

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
```

And I've also tried the follow in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'allow,deny';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array(
'allow % from all'
```

as well as

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'www.domain.co.uk/phpmyadmin';
```

But whenever I enter www.domain.co.uk/phpmyadmin it's redirected to localhost/phpmyadmin. It works fine on the machine itself, but I need remote access.

Comment: did you do anything with default configurations? How does it respond if you install with default settings (except username and pass)?

Comment: Besides the above, no. I get the same results from a fresh install and from trying all of the above.

Comment: what about leaving PmaAbsoluteUri setting empty, maybe that will force use of localhost?

Comment: PmaAbsoluteUri isn't in the config by default, I added it. But leaving it empty and giving it the value "localhost" makes no difference.

Comment: why did you add it?

Comment: I googled around looking for a solution before I posted here. They seemed to work for other people on similar setups.

Comment: I'll check my configuration and see whats wrong. may be post your full config file hiding some sec relevant info

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's [config.inc.php](http://pastebin.com/JsR3SXZC) and [apache.conf](http://pastebin.com/7tWbCB5h).

Comment: config.inc.php have a line
// Load autoconf local config
include('/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php');
What are contents of /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php?

Comment: It's empty. I just removed, purged and reinstalled phpMyAdmin and it was empty before and after.

Comment: So you install using apt-get or something like that not that you are downloading form phpmyadmin site?

Comment: Yeah, sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin.

Comment: Try purging it i.e sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin and manually check and delete all config files (remember to back up) then reinstall. Personally I would just download phpmyadmin and install it myself!

Comment: This is going to seem like a really stupid mistake, but if I add an ending slash to the url I am able to access it remotely, but without the slash it redirects to localhost still... Thanks for the helping anyway!

Comment: then change $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'www.domain.co.uk/phpmyadmin'; to $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'www.domain.co.uk/phpmyadmin/'; adding the slash